# How do I render return values of a node-mssql statement with Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, node-mssql

I've got a Node.js server with Express and Jade running. On an HTTP request the server will execute the following function:

```
function home(req, res) {

  res.render("site/index", {recordset: recordset}); //render the Jade template
}
```

Now I would like to pass in an array to the above recordset variable that I can loop through in Jade to populate a drop-down on my html page. I've retrieved the desired array like so:

```
function runSQLSelect() {
      sql.connect(config.db, function(err) {
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.query("select MyColumn FROM MyTable", function(err, recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
        });
      });
}
```

What is a proper way to asynchronously run the SQL query and pass the subsequent result into my Jade template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have the res.render in the callback from query.

```
function runSQLSelect(callback) {
      sql.connect(config.db, function(err) {
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.query("select MyColumn FROM MyTable", function(err, recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
        callback(recordset);
        });
      });
}

function home(req, res) {
  runQSQLSelect( function(result) {
      res.render("site/index", {recordset: result}); //render the Jade template
  });
}
```

Note, you may want to have your callback invoked in an async fashion, using `setImmediate`, you also might consider having your runSQLSelect callback make use of the standard node practice of accepting two parameters `callback(err,data)`.